# Referencing parameters in the CSS section of a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function toggles all checkboxes in a given column of an HTML table when selecting or deselecting a checkbox.

```
function GlobalCheckboxSwitch0(checkboxID, tableID)
{
    if ($(checkboxID).is(':checked'))
    {
        $('#table0 input[type=checkbox]').each(function ()
        {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });

    } 
    else 
    {
        $('#table0 input[type=checkbox]').each(function ()
        {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });
    }
}
```

Invoking it like this works only for **table0**:

```
        <input type="checkbox" id="selectall0" onClick="GlobalCheckboxSwitch0('#selectall0', '#table0')">
```

The problem is that **table0** is hard coded in the function.

With the help of the second parameter **tableID** I would like it to work for any table ID.

**selectall0** is the ID of the checkbox.

Trying to refer the **tableID** parameter like this:

```
$('$(tableID) input[type=checkbox]')
```

yields a syntax error.

What should I change in the way I refer to **tableID**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `tableID` selector the same way you do for `checkboxID` along with `find()`.

You can also skip the `if` and the `each` and do the following:

```
function GlobalCheckboxSwitch0(checkboxID, tableID) {
  var allChecked = $(checkboxID).is(':checked');
  $(tableID).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', allChecked );

}
```

jQuery will do the `each` internally

Comment: I would rename the parameter 'tableSelector' to avoid confusion since you're including `#`.  You could send `'table.selected'` or any other selector, it's not really just the id.  Same with checkboxID...

Answer (score 0):

It's a jQuery selector syntax error, to be precise - it's not actually a JavaScript syntax error.

You need to learn concatenation, which means joining strings and variables/expressions.

As it stands...

```
$('$(tableID) input[type=checkbox]')
```

...will be executed literally. In other words, you're telling jQuery to go find an element whose **tag name** is `tableID`.

Instead you need to concatenate between the formulaic and dynamic parts of the jQuery selector. Concatenation in JavaScript is done via `+`.

```
$('#'+tableID+' input[type=checkbox]') //<-- note #
```

Comment: Need to get rid of `()` in selector and OP is passing in `#` already

Comment: Somehow this yields:

Uncaught Error:
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $(##table0) input[type=checkbox]

Comment: Lazy on my part. Edited.